# Strange sum problem

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elegant workaround for JavaScript floating point number problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

```
var sum = 0;
$('[id$=percentOfTotalEditor]').each(
    function () {
        var igEditor = $find(this.id);
        var value = igEditor.get_value();
        sum += value;
    }
);
```

Then you'll see the magic:

sum == 1.1, value == 0.1. But after sum += value, sum == 1.2000000000000001

WTF!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers in javascript are stored as floating points - there will be some degree of imprecision - please see linked article, or search this site for floating point arithmetic for many explanations.

Comment: ok, have you any idea, how to solve this

Comment: @JooLio - did you look at the linked duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this question is a duplicate as Paddy has suggested.  Still, here's another Javascript library that will allow you to work with precise decimal numbers (up to a point): http://blog.brewsession.com/2008/06/28/problematic-decimal-arithmetic-in-javascript/